# How to get all products that are using the default ( admin ) scope values when in a store scope

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, products, scope

I want to create a admin Grid that displays all products that are using the default ( admin 0 ) scope values when i am in a store scope.

How can I filter a collection to get this desire result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Ryan

Answer (score 2):

You can get the default store id with

```
$defaultStoreId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getDefaultGroup()->getDefaultStoreId();
```

then you can use that ID to filter the product collection.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStoreFilter($defaultStoreId)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

That should give you what you are looking for.

I have not tested it so please let me know if it does not work so I can make adjustments.

Comment: Hi Phil, Thanks for your reply. What I am looking to achieve is getting all products that are using admin scope values (0) when I am in a store scope. Say suppose I have a website test.com with store A, and have 10 products under this. I set the price for all 10 products under Admin scope (0). Then I switch to Store A scope and change the price of 5 products. Now I want to list only those 5 products which are using the admin scope value (0). Hope this makes sense and look forward to your reply.